# undefined is not a function in karma with angular.js

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

filterTest.js

```
'use strict';
describe('test the reverse string filter',function(){

  var customFilter;
  beforeEach(module('directiveApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($filter){
      customFilter = $filter('reversing');
  }));
  it('passing a filter test',function(){
        expect(customFilter('HELLO')).toBe('OLLEH');
  });
});
```

filterModule.js

```
angular.module('directiveApp').filter('reversing',function(text){
  return text.split("").reverse().join("");
});
```

filterTest.js is my test file in which i am trying to test the filter that i have created in 'directiveApp' module which reverses the string. When i run `karma start` it was giving an error:

TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'customFilter('HELLO')') in /var/www/html/Directive/tests/testFilter.js (line 10)
    /var/www/html/Directive/tests/testFilter.js:10:25

I am unable figure it out, what wrong with it. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your filter is not defined correctly. It should be:

```
angular.module('directiveApp').filter('reversing', function() {
  return function(text) {
    return text.split("").reverse().join("");
  };
});
```

Comment: Even thought i have replaced the with this, its giving the same error.

Comment: It's most probably caused by a karma misconfiguration. Have you configure karma to load your filter JS file?

Comment: files: [
      'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/*.js',
      'test/*.js'
    ],